# Good books on NMR

Tags: resource-recommendations, spectroscopy, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

I need some help in finding a good book on NMR spectroscopy that focuses more on the physical aspects of the phenomenon and not so much on the chemical application. All the books I've read on that topic include only qualitative explanations, and I'm looking for something that would treat the subject at hand more rigorously, in the physical and mathematical sense.

Comment: Related: [Resources for learning Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry). Check out *Spectroscopy* and *Nuclear magnetic resonance* subsections therein.